# php mail take long time and it arrive to junk mail

Tags: php, email, mysqli

when i use PHP mail it take a long time to be received

and it arrive to junk email

and i send mail online i have a host and domain name on godaddy.com

how to solve this 2 problems

```
$to=$_SESSION['e'];
    $subject='NEW TASK';
    $headers ="from: T-Square.com ";
    $headers .= "From: T-SQUARE <T-SQUARE.COM>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Organization: T-SQUARE COMPANY\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;

    $message="YOU HAVE A NEW TASK PLEASE CHECK IT www.eiwms-progroup.com";
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Simple solution, use PHPMailer

Comment: Google what is "PHPMailer"

Comment: Google for PHPMailer. And @MuthaFury, PHPMailer doesn't always solve the spam issue as well. You can, for example, use an external site to solve the mail sending issue. Try SendGrid, they got a PHP API as well, which you can use to easily send emails.

Comment: @Janno For me most of the time it solves most of the issue :D but it is true sometimes it doesn't solve spam issue depending on the mailing server that is being sent from.